# Backbone router events - always two events per route?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using the newer Backbone event listening mechanism. In my router initialize method, that looks like this:

```
     this.listenTo(this,'all',function(route,action){
           console.log('router was invoked,  route:',route,'action:',action);
       });
```

in the debugger, when I put a breakpoint on the console.log statement, I get something unsuspected.

For each new route, I get this combination

```
route   action

route:x  null
route     x
```

so in real life that looks like:

```
route        action 

route:home   null
route        home


route:index null
route       index
```

so my question is - why are there two separate events being fired for each route, and why do they differ like the above?

here is some proof:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Router.route` fires two separate events per `route` operation:

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
  if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
  if (_.isFunction(name)) {
    callback = name;
    name = '';
  }
  if (!callback) callback = this[name];
  var router = this;
  Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
    var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
    if (router.execute(callback, args, name) !== false) {
      router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
      router.trigger('route', name, args);
      Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
    }
  });
  return this;
},
```

http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-152

The first one calls the actual trigger with `router, ['route:' + name].concat(args)` and the second one first the `route` event.